# For any nonempty set X construct a surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any nonempty set X construct a surjection: $S:P(X) -> x$ (Hint: Do not forget to identify for all S ∈ P(X) )

So I know a possible solution is P({X}) -> x. But I do not understand why. If someone can explain this more in depth or provide a more intuitive example, that would be great. Also what does the hint mean?

Comment: What is x? Is it $X$ or $\{X\}$ you are taking the power set of? (Does it matter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to construct a surjection from the power set of a set to the set itself.

That is, for a nonempty set $X$, you desire a surjection $S: P(X) \rightarrow X$.

Indeed, one way would be to proceed as follows:

For any singleton set, i.e., a set of the form $\{x\}$ for some $x \in X$, let us decide that $S$ will simply remove the brackets. In other words, that $S(\{x\}) = x \in X$.

To ensure the function is defined for all elements of $P(X)$, though, we will have to decide what to do with the remaining subsets. Since $X$ is nonempty, we know it contains some element $a$. Let us just send every non-singleton set, then, to $a \in X$.

Now we have a well-defined surjective function $S: P(X) \rightarrow X$.

---

**Example:** Given $X := \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, let $a := 1 \in X$, and define $S$ as above.

Then $S: P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\}) \rightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is a surjective function.

It maps $\{1\} \mapsto 1$, $\{2\} \mapsto 2$, $\{3\} \mapsto 3$, $\{4\} \mapsto 4$, and sends every other subset of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to $1$.

Comment: What does := mean

Comment: Also this is a very nice (surjective) construction.

Comment: As an example, $a := 1$ is shorthand for "Let $a = 1$" or "Define $a$ to be $1$."